# JQuery obtener parámetros de un For Each JSP JSTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Como hacer para pasar el parámetro `JSP` a `JQuery`, si se tienen los valores en un bucle.
Este es el código **"JSP"**

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.codigo_Pers}" /><input type="hidden" value="${dato.codigo_Pers}" class="txtCodigoOculto"></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.nombre_Pers}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Pat_Pers}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Mat_Pers}" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Modificar" class="btnModificar">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Al dar click en el botón **Modificar** necesito que obtenga el valor de `${dato.codigo_Pers}`, como ven he creado un `<input type="hidden">` opcional para capturar ese valor en `JQuery`.
Intente hacer esto en **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnModificar').click(function() {
        var codigoPers = $('.txtCodigoOculto').val();
        alert(codigoPers);
    });
});
```

Pero recibo el mismo valor de la primera fila de la tabla para todas las filas que seleccione, es decir si en mi primero fila tengo como parámetro `codigo_Pers = P-001`, entonces al seleccionar el **botón de la segunda o cualquier otra fila de la tabla** me arroja el mismo valor `P-001`.
Un favor necesito corregir este error, cualquier solución parecida o diferente sería de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar `$('.txtCodigoOculto')` estás seleccionando todos los elementos de tipo `<input class="txtCodigoOculto">` que serán igual a la cantidad de filas que tengas, entonces al intentar usar la función `val()` le estás pidiendo el valor a un listado de elementos, que como jquery está implementado te está retornando el valor del primer elemento. Lo adecuado sería que hagas referencia a la misma fila y luego al `<input class="txtCodigoOculto">` a la que también pertenece el boton desde donde diste click.
Hay muchas formas de hacer referencia a tal `input` una puede ser la siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnModificar').click(function() {
        var codigoPers = $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=hidden]').val()
        alert(codigoPers);
    });
});
```

`this` hace referencia al elemento del cual se emitió el evento(o sea el boton donde se hizo click), luego busca al `parent` que es una columna `<td>`, esta columna tiene varias hermanas y se obtienen usando `siblings` entonces de todas ellas se busca el `input[type=hidden]` usando `find` para obtener su valor usando la función `val()`.

Comment: Christian eres bueno gracias por tu ayuda no sabia que existían esas funciones en JQuery, solo una pregunta no se si podrás responder como haría para buscar el valor de otro campo oculto pero esta vez por su nombre del campo oculto (`name`), pero de todos modos gracias por responder.

Comment: haciendo target al atributo: `'input[name=foo]'`

Comment: He reemplazado `input[type=hidden]` por `input[name=(mitxtname)]` pero me arroja `undefined`, dime estoy haciendo bien al reemplazar el código o esta mal.

Comment: tengo entendido que no puedes usar caracteres especial para nombrar un atributo salvo unos cuantos, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/14394034) una discución sobre ello.

Comment: Bien gracias por tu ayuda, acabo de descubrir que también lo podemos hacer de la siguiente manera claro si la etiqueta `<td class="id">` tiene una clase como el que pongo como ejemplo, entonces en JQuery hacemos lo siguiente: `var codigoPers = $(this).parent().parent().find("td.id").text();` y para mostrarlo en mensaje `alert(codigoPers);`, (me di cuenta que `parent()` hace retroceder etiquetas) esto funciona y ya no es necesario poner un `<input type="hidden">`. Bueno quería compartir esto por si a alguien más le sirve y agradecerte también por tu tiempo y la molestia por responder.

Comment: `parent()` no hace retroceder etiquetas, lo que hace es buscar al nodo padre del elemento en cuestión. Se puede interpretar igual la funcionalidad pero el concepto correcto es el que te menciono.